# Restore folder that is deleted locally from SVN

Tags: ubuntu, svn, tortoisesvn

One large folder is tagged with D (deleted) then I enter "svn st".
The delete of the folder is not committed and is local.

I need to regret this delete.
This is what I have tried:

- update to the rev number that is the latest.
- cleanup and delete the parent folder and run update.
  I tried to update to an older one, but it's still the same.

Working in Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried reverting the folder? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1790283/4248273

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is a `revert` command.

On Ubuntu (and also Windows), you can  run the following command line(s):

```
svn revert nameOfDeletedDirectory
```

On Windows, with `TortoiseSVN` (as you tagged your question with it, I add this answer) you can do it as follows:

1. Right-click on an upper folder
2. Select `TortoiseSVN ==> Revert...` menu
3. Check the boxes related to the deleted folders
4. Click on `OK` button